# How to get different country time into single page using flex or flash (action script 3) because getTime() used for get current time only

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

i am beginner dont know how do display all country time into a single page using action script 3 in flex . do u know any example time code refer me . i will try that code .

Answer (score 1):

In Actionscript/Flex, you can only get either the local time, which is from the user's operating system, or the UTC time. You'll have to find a way of converting UTC to the user's time - or use externalInterface to communicate with something like java.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone zone) method to create a Calendar object of a timezone. TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() will give you list of inbuild timezones supported by Java. You can find out the timezones you want and using the id can create the TimeZone object from TimeZone.getTimeZone(String ID)

Comment: thanks Bhushan - it's information very usefule to me . i will try that . if any example in flex (action script 3)